# Custom Splashscreen on Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: boot, autostart, windows-embedded-compact

I want my Windows Embedded Compact 7 Device to start an Application after boot without the OS showing at any time. For the time that windows is booting I'd like to show some Fullscreen Logo image. Any way to do this?

A Solution without the need for Platform Builder would be preferred. When the Application terminates the normal Windows EC7 Desktop shall be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will need platform builder, because you need to recompile bootloader, to get custom image embedded in the code.

When you install PB check under BOOTLOADER\Display\bsp_logo.c

Regards,
Luka